# How else can I say "went out of sync"?

Tags: synonyms

I'm trying to improve the following sentence: "Search criteria and results went out of sync." How can I rephrase this sentence so that the meaning is retained without using "out of sync"?

Comment: Can you give a little more context?

Comment: Think of google, you searched for something, got the results, then you decided to search for something else, you typed it in again, but the results still reflect the previous search you did. Now you are in a situation when the search criteria (new search) is out of sync with the results (from old search).

Answer (score 1):

You could say

> The search criteria and the results did not match.
>
> The results did not correspond to the search criteria.

Note that if you *wanted* to use the phrase "out of sync", this sounds more natural to me than your example above:

> The search criteria and the results **were** out of sync.

Comment: The question uses inchoative *go*, describing a change of state from in sync to out of sync.  In honkaboy's answer, this is reflected with *no longer* and *have expired*.  The sentences in this answer don't have anything like that, so I don't think they're quite what the OP intended.

Answer (score 1):

I'm also having a little trouble understanding the context and what you really want to say, but perhaps one of the following is what you want:

> These results no longer match the search criteria.

or

> These results no longer reflect the search criteria.

or

> These results have expired and no longer reflect the search criteria.

Answer (score 0):

Try

> Search criteria and results began to diverge.

or

> Increasingly, results failed to match search criteria.

or

> Increasingly, search criteria failed to produce useable results.